# Using Sprout SEO, how do I use the seoDivider setting in templates?

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

[Sprout SEO](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/seo/) has a setting in the admin screens to "Select the character that will be used between Title segments". I think it's called `seoDivider`, but I can't see how to use this in my templates, and can't see any reference to it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The SEO Divider setting will be used if you select the *"Append Site Name to all Titles"* setting on the Basic SEO tab of your Default, and then override your title via code or a Meta Basic Field type.

For example, if the pipe character is selected as the divider:

```
Code Override Blog Post Name | Website Name

Meta Basic Field Override Title Value | Website Name
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. So if I'm doing something like this https://gist.github.com/engram-design/be3fe032348f4461dd89 there's no way to access that setting from the template when constructing title strings?

Comment: @PhilGyford At the moment no, but I think I see the benefit.  You want to update something like this: `page.title ~ ' - ' ~ suffix` to `page.title ~ '  ' ~ craft.sproutSeo.seoDivider ~ '  ' ~ suffix`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If I'm manually setting that title string in my templates it'll be a bit confusing to a client using the CMS if they come across that setting but it doesn't do anything. So I'd like to use the setting in my templates so it works as the user would expect (given they shouldn't need to know how it's put together under the hood).